# Run shell script located on Windows path with WSL2

Tags: ubuntu, sh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have activated WSL2 and installed Ubuntu as the distro. Can I run shell-scripts that are located on a Windows path in my WSL2 distro by double-clicking?

Comment: You could in theory execute them at Windows level by opening them with bash. Problem is that bash will need a -c flag to execute it

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be specifically about programming, and may be better suited for [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/).